# first visit to site loads page twice

Tags: delegate, user-controls

I create a new Site Collection within an existing SP Web Application.  The new Site Collection is created as a child of an existing Site Collection (the Root Site Collection in the Web Application) using a Managed Path.

After the user creates the new Site Collection, the first request from a second user to the site causes the page to load twice.  I notice this because the site collection has a custom Delegate Control provisioned to it.  I have attached my debugger and set my breakpoint on the Load event of the user control's code behind.

I've tested with the .ascx with AutoEventWireup set as both "true" and "false" and implementing my Load event as overriding the OnLoad event and using naming convention for Page_Load().

One more tidbit: Within control's Load event, I am setting a "ViewState" variable on first time in.  I check it again the second time in, and the value is not there.

My thought on this is that SharePoint, internally, is processing the first GET request for the new user and then adding them to the AllUsers collection.  It then, internally, reruns the pipeline for the Page all over again.

Can anyone validate my assumption about what is going on?  Or maybe shed some light on why I am seeing the double Load event on my delegate control?

FWIW, it is a SP2010 web application that has been upgraded from 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I found a custom HTTP Module that was forcing a redirect.  Have to watch out for these!